# How to create a autorun/.exe file of database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, installation, windows-installer

I'm developing a CMS and I'm using SQL Server with it. I want to automatically create my database in SQL Server 2008 when my app is installed.

I can generate a script. I'm wondering that there might be a way that I can install SQL script in a database using an MSI file.

e.g. in this link we can install database using a MSI file

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23654

I just wanna know how can we do it. Is it created using SQL Server or Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

you can attach a database through the app.config. in your installation you should copy this database to the right place.

Look here how to set your connection string:
http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: Wanna ask you Will I be able to attach this with database with sql server and what will happen if I dont have sql server

Comment: Sql Server must be installed before. Otherwise this will not work. You may check whether sql server is installed in your installation procedure (msi). Or consider using sql ce, so you won't need the server.

Comment: Bu if the mdf is installed then the sql admin can make use of it,like detach and install on other computer or generate script. Is there any way that even admin cannot open the database and the mdf cannot be opened explicitly

Comment: I don't know a way to workaround that. sql admin has all rights to do that. You could use a sql ce, which you can create and encrypt easily. The encryption password is stored in the app.config, which you can although encrypt. So a computer admin wouldn't be able to open this database.

Comment: may be with the sql server this encryption procedure is possible too.

Comment: I m waiting if someone can give me any hint